# Introduce a Gray Scale to Negative Voted Questios

Tags: discussion, voting, spam

Was wondering if it would be helpful to moderators and to keep this site cleaner to do following.

On each negative Vote on the Question the Font gets reduced in gray scale color.

So for example on this one:

[image: gray scale]

With 5 down votes the text should be barley visible ?

It is a shame the Spammer gets more that 30 minutes of promotion and advertisement without been able to do much until a moderator takes action.

UPDATE:

Statistical it happens more and more and as you can see 4 down votes and not one FLAG ? Means 4 users had to open the question and then all they did is downvote.

[image: scam]

EDIT:

Well in conclusion let it just put this way

It is not acceptable in 21 century on a high profile and high traffic web site to have Spams just sitting there for a hour or more.

The current system

> There is an automated system - it requires 6 flags and not votes see
>   this meta answer –  Mark

needs some overhaul.

Comment: In this case wouldn't flagging for spam (e.g. 5 flags) have deleted the article quicker. Also keeping it visible means that more people can see to flag it quicker

Comment: @Mark it was Flagged and down voted and Voted to Close still it was there a hour later. The problem is there is no Automated system to deal with Spam, so even after 5 Negative votes it was still there.

Comment: There is an automated system - it requires 6 flags and not votes see this [meta answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/136010)

Comment: The good news is that the chance that a mod isn't around for an hour and spam appearing and it being a high traffic hour all at the same time are probably pretty low.

Comment: @dwightk where did you get those statistics from ? so you do not mind having a free advertisement for a hour from time to time? it just sits there poking you right in to your brain, insulting you ect..and there is nothing much you can do about other than pray a mod is around or 6 people will flag it, since when did we give up the fight on Spam?

Comment: I've been pretty active for 50 days and I've seen 3 spam posts. That isn't bad. It only takes 3 flags to move it from the front page.

Comment: @Buscar웃 It only needs 3 flags to remove it from the front page - it lookalike we need to make more people flag rather than vote if they had then the question would have been hidden with **less** effort than you are requesting (on the next spam I saw I added a comment to remind people to **flag**

Comment: @Mark it is not working as you can see in my update

Comment: @dwightk here is new one so you can update your statistics.

Comment: @Buscar웃 We need to train people to flag which seems to work as this one was not on the front page within 30 mins - http://apple.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/59081

Comment: Great now I got negative 102 points for trying to be helpful ??

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying that commenting in the Spam post is OK, in order to inform others to flag?  I thought that is a no no, no commenting in the Scam post.

Comment: ok, why am I bothering at all, now I got penalized with -100) for posting information about flagging in the said spam that ended up with 8 negative votes and not single Flag.

Comment: @Buscar웃 don't worry about negative points like those, they should go away when the question is removed.

Comment: @dwightk the point is the Moderator was fast to give me 100 negative points, but the Spam post was still up ?

Comment: *"4 users had to open the question and then all they did is downvote." "8 negative votes and not single Flag."* How do you know they didn't flag?

Comment: Also, your -100 for posting spam shouldn't have come from your answer to the spam question in the screenshot in your question here — the question was spam-deleted but **balpha deleted your answer and didn't spam-delete it**, so that shouldn't have cost you 100 reputation. (can someone confirm?) Did you post another answer to a different spam post? Link?

Comment: @dwightk Having a post deleted due to spam will cost you 100 reputation which is removed from a user in private (not shown publicly on the reputation history). This won't get put back when the question is removed.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think this is required.

The main issue is that people need to flag this as spam, down votes have no effect.

After 3 flags it will not be on the front page - so takes less effort by us that your suggestion

From meta stackexchnage [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/136010)

> The spam flag is designed to eliminate posts with no relevant content and to penalize the authors:
>
> - 3 flags (spam or offensive): post is banished from the front page.
> - 6 flags (spam or offensive): post is locked, deleted, and the first revision owner loses 100 reputation.
> - 1 flag from a moderator has the same effect as 6 flags from normal users: instant destruction.
> - Because a question with 6 flags is locked and deleted by the Community user, a 10k reputation user cannot undelete it.
> - Each flag carries an implicit downvote for calculating the post's score (it does not affect the user's reputation).

Comment: Thank you. The fact that this ?user got a hour of free advertisement! is not relevant here? I can not speak for others and why did they not Flag the post, but I see they used they hard earned points to vote it down. As far I understand Flagging still requires moderators attention. These types of flags receive an extremely high priority in the moderation queue.

Comment: Spam flags as noted in that answer do not require moderators